# ffmpeg setpts filter not applied to output

Tags: ffmpeg

Learning to speed up and slow down video using the ffmpeg setpts filter, but I am struggling to get a simple expression to work.

ffmpeg -i .\F5-ff.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.25*PTS" ff-test3.mp4

I get the output file, but it is not any faster than the original.

I'm sorry if this has already been addressed. Most related post I've found were trouble shooting more complex operations past this step. Im working in a powershell terminal fyi.

Comment: joe5's ownanswer is good, and I hope the document below can help others.
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video PS: I can't add a comment because of my low reputation, so I add a new answer...

Answer (score 3):

Just realized what was happening...I was looking at the total length of the video, but closer look showed that video portion was actually faster, but total length of file remained unchanged because audio track had not been shortened.